# Is content of the pg_autovacuum saved when pg_dumpall is used to backup the database?

Tags: postgresql

From the docs:
*pg_dumpall also dumps global objects that are common to all databases. (pg_dump does not     save these objects.) This currently includes information about database users and groups, tablespaces, and properties such as access permissions that apply to databases as a whole.
Since pg_dumpall reads tables from all databases you will most likely have to connect as a database superuser in order to produce a complete dump.*

I would assume yes, but I am not completely sure.

Comment: Per @JoshKupershmidt's comment, I'm guessing you're on an ancient PostgreSQL version?

Answer (score 1):

`pg_dumpall` is simply a wrapper around `pg_dump`. It notes farther down in the documentation for the `-n --schema` flag that it only dumps non-system schemas.

> Dump only schemas matching schema; this selects both the schema itself, and all its contained objects. When this option is not specified, all non-system schemas in the target database will be dumped.

The system level things that `pg_dumpall` dumps instead of `pg_dump` are listed at the top of the `pg_dumpall` documentation, as you quoted above, which doesn't include a mention of system catalog tables.

So it shouldn't actually dump out the contents of `pg_catalog.pg_autovacuum`.

Which is actually a good thing. The system catalog tables are an intimate part of each PostgreSQL database, and automatically generated for you when you do a `CREATE DATABASE`. Their entries generally only make sense within the context of the database they were created in.

Additionally, [pg_catalog.pg_autovacuum](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/catalog-pg-autovacuum.html) was last seen in the 8.1 to 8.3 releases of PostgreSQL, all of which have been unsupported since at least February 2013, so hopefully this is part of a migration path to a newer supported release.